# Is there a way to speed up these functions?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, bioinformatics, numba

I have these functions. They are working perfectly, but is there a way to speed them up? I tried to split the dataset, but it takes the same or more time than the original functions. I'm working with big arrays (1Mill+X2504X2). create_needed_pos takes arount 350sec for 1.2millX2054X2 array, but my biggest is around 10bilionx2054x2.

```
@nb.njit
def create_needed_pos(chr_pos, pos):

    needed_pos = nb.typed.List.empty_list(nb.int32)
    for i in range(len(chr_pos)):
        for k in range(len(pos)):
            if chr_pos[i] == pos[k]:
                if i == k == 1:
                    needed_pos = nb.typed.List([pos[k]])
                else:
                    needed_pos.append(pos[k])
    return needed_pos
@nb.njit
def create_mat(geno):
    # create matrix as np.uint8 (1 byte) instead of list of python integers (8 byte)
    # also no need to dynamically resize / increase list size
    geno_mat = np.zeros((len(geno[:, 0]), len(geno[1, :])), dtype=np.uint8)

    for i in np.arange(len(geno[:, 0])):
        for k in np.arange(len(geno[1, :])):
            g = geno[i, k]

            # nested ifs to avoid duplicate comparisons
            if g[0] == 0:
                if g[1] == 0:
                    geno_mat[i, k] = 2
                elif g[1] == 1:
                    geno_mat[i, k] = 1
                else:
                    geno_mat[i, k] = 9
            elif g[0] == 1:
                if g[1] == 0:
                    geno_mat[i, k] = 1
                elif g[1] == 1:
                    geno_mat[i, k] = 0
                else:
                    geno_mat[i, k] = 9
            else:
                geno_mat[i, k] = 9
    return geno_mat
```

Comment: look up `np.select` for the `create_mat` function

Comment: Do you need to check `g[1] == 1` and assign 0 to `geno_mat[i, k]`? `geno_mat` is already `zoeros`.

Comment: It would help us tremendously if you can provide a [minimal working reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example. In this case that includes a small example of your dataset (just a few elements) and the (expected) output. Also could you describe the functionality of the code in words?

Comment: My first instinct is to avoid if statements but does that make it any faster using jit? Anyway, you can avoid some else statements by having `geno_mat[i, k] = 9` before the `if: elif` block and just letting that be overridden if one of the conditions is met